# difference between "svn update DIR" and "cd DIR && svn update"

Tags: linux, svn

What is the difference between running: `svn update DIR` and running `svn update` with DIR as cwd? (`DIR` is my checkout's root).

Intuitively, I'd expect the two to do the same thing, but I noticed that when running the former (when cwd is outside the local checkout), sometimes not all updates are fetched. But then running the latter fetches what it needs to.

(running on linux)

EDIT: to all the skeptics, here's a session I've just had:

```
$ svn up DIR/
Password for 'xxx': ...
Skipped 'DIR'
$ cd DIR/
$ svn up 
Password for 'xxx': ...
U    aaa
U    bbb
...
 U   .
Updated to revision 8965.
$
```

Comment: Not clear to me why this question is voted to be closed. Isn't svn a "software tool commonly used by programmers"?

Comment: Your results are still surprising since `DIR/` should be canonicalized into `DIR`.  Can you post the output of `svn --version`?  I can't replicate this with the newest versions of svn, I suspect you've just run into an old bug.

Comment: @BenReser `version 1.6.17 (r1128011)`

Answer (score 0):

The following is pure wild speculation. I know virtually nothing about svn and nothing about its internals.

That being said I would guess that from outside the checkout svn looks in the current directory for configuration information, doesn't find any, and then does the minimum necessary to update the given directory (by reading its specific configuration information) and that from inside the checkout svn operates in a more recursive/project-aware mode because the local directory contains the configuration it needs.

Examining the operational differences between the two runs with something like `strace` might provide some clues.

Assuming there is a difference after all and what you are seeing isn't merely later changes getting pulled in by a second update (with an active project for example).

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference.  `svn update` without a target specified simply uses `.` as the target.

Based on your updated question.  There are two ways you get the "Skipped 'DIR/'" message:

1. You had a path in conflict (either the target or one of it's parents) and you would have had to resolve it between the two commands.  Which seems unlikely given your example
2. You had typoed the path in the svn up command and have the cdspell option turned on in your shell.

Take this for example:

```
$ ls -d trunk
trunk/

$ svn up truunk/
Skipped 'truunk'

$ cd truunk/
trunk/

$ svn up
At revision 1540579.
```

If you have a simple reproduction method I'd be interested in it.

Comment: Go read the code for yourself.  svn_cl__update() at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/update-cmd.c and svn_opt_push_implicit_dot_target() in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/opt.c  If you can find a difference it's a bug that you should report if you can reproduce it in 1.8.4.

Comment: This is how it reproduces for me: in your `$HOME` (for example), create a symlink to the root of some svn checkout you have. Then: `cd $HOME; svn up ./symlink_to_checkout/`